# Best way to store number of children in parent table in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, rdbms

I am trying to implement a simple product system in MYSQL, where a product can have many comments. There is a foreign key product_id in the comment table referencing the product table. I want to store the number of comments of the product as a field in the product table for sorting purpose. It can be achieved by creating two triggers on the comment table like this

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER comment_incr_trig
AFTER INSERT ON `COMMENT` FOR EACH ROW
begin
    UPDATE PRODUCT SET NUM_OF_COMMENT = NUM_OF_COMMENT + 1 WHERE ID = NEW.PRODUCT_ID;
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER comment_decr_trig
AFTER DELETE ON `COMMENT` FOR EACH ROW
begin
    UPDATE PRODUCT SET NUM_OF_COMMENT = NUM_OF_COMMENT - 1 WHERE ID = OLD.PRODUCT_ID;
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

However, is there any mechanism in MYSQL that can directly bind one field in the parent table to the number of children without using trigger?

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would generally recommend against storing such *derived information*. You can easily compute on the fly in your queries whenever you need it.

To avoid repeatedly typing the same query again, one solution would be to create a view:

```
create view product_view(id, num_of_comments) as
select
    p.id,
    c.num_of_comments
from product p
left join (
    select product_id, count(*) num_of_comments
    from comment
    group by product_id
) c on c.product_id = p.id
```

You can expand the view with more columns coming from the `product` table (I could not add more since the only column that is showned in your question is `product(id)`).